# Text in table row appearing next to image but not where I wanted it to be placed

Tags: html, image, text, html-table, html-email

I'm not sure what the reason is behind this issue and I can't figure out why it is doing it so maybe  you  can help? This is a screenshot of what is happening: http://puu.sh/4SbM3.png

This is for a html email so I have to use the table methods. This is the code I have for that particular section of the table:

```
    <td align="left" width="214" 
    <td> <a href="http://www.lendfair.co.uk/apply-for-a-loan.php">
    <img src="images/apply.jpg" alt="Apply" width="60" height="25"></a>
    For a Guarantor Loan
    </td>
```

It looks to me like the text is lining up with the bottom of the picture but I would like it to line up with the center instead and I can't figure out how to do it. If you  could help it would be most appreciated.

Comment: your html here looks a bid weird with the first <td opening...(broken)

Comment: thats wierd, it the second td in the one tr but thats just an empty one to take up the space and it does display correctly positioning and the image showing wise on the whole thing as well

Comment: Seems like you have a <td> within a <td>

Comment: here this will hopefully make it clearer on what i have here is a screenshot of everything i have at the moment [link](http://puu.sh/4Sc2A.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="images/apply.jpg" alt="Apply" width="60" height="25" style="vertical-align:middle;">
```

[W3Schools Vertical Align Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

Comment: This did exactly what I needed thanks will accept as answer as soon as I can